# How to do this in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

Sorry about the poor question title, it's just that this seems to big for a title. So here's the dirt:

I am making a game (obviously) and I want the enemies to shoot (not necessarily at the player). I want the shoot method to be in the Enemies file, so as not to clutter up my HelloWorldLayer.m file even more. Here's what I'm using right now:

HelloWorldLayer.m

```
-(void)addEnemy:(BigAndStrongEnemy *)enemy {
enemy = nil;
if((arc4random() % 4) == 3) {
    enemy = [BigAndStrongEnemy enemy];
} else {
    enemy = [SmallAndFastEnemy enemy];
}

if(buffDude.position.y > character.position.y || buffDude.position.y < (character.position.y + 10)) {

}

int rand = arc4random() % 320;

if((arc4random() % 2 == 1)) {
    [enemy setPosition:ccp(0,rand)];
}else{
    [enemy setPosition:ccp(480,rand)];
}
[self animateEnemy:enemy];
[self addChild:enemy];
}

-(void)animateEnemy:(BigAndStrongEnemy *)enemy2 {
    float randX = arc4random() % 480;
    float randY = arc4random() % 320;
    int rand = arc4random() % 320;

CGPoint moveToPoint = CGPointMake(randX, (randY - rand));

[enemies addObject:enemy2];

action = [CCSequence actions:
          [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccpMult(ccpNormalize(ccpSub(moveToPoint, enemy2.position)), 75)],
          [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(buffDude.position.x,buffDude.position.y)],
          nil];

CCCallFuncO *a = [CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:self selector:(@selector(shoot:)) object:enemy2];
CCSequence *s = [CCSequence actions:action,a, nil];

CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:s];

[enemy2 runAction:repeat];
}
```

And here's the Shoot info from the Enemies class:

Enemies.m:

```
    -(void)shoot:(id)sender {
    BigAndStrongEnemy *enemy = (BigAndStrongEnemy *)sender;
    [enemy shoot];
}

-(void)spriteMoveFinished:(id)sender {
    CCSprite *b = (CCSprite *)sender;
    [self removeChild:b cleanup:YES];
}

-(void)shoot {
    buffDude = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bigAndStrongEnemy.gif"];
    CCSprite *b = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bullet.gif"];
    b.position = ccp(self.position.x,self.position.y);
    b.tag = 2;
    [self addChild:b];
    [bullets addObject:b];


CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

CGPoint point = CGPointMake((winSize.width - (winSize.width - self.position.x)),0);

[b runAction:[CCSequence actions:
              [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.5 position:point],
              [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)],
              nil]];
}
```

Every time the 3 seconds goes by, the app crashes, and goes to the breakpoint in the CCCallFuncO file. I haven't touched it, is the thing. I am completely confused. Any help is greatly appreciated. Sorry about the long question. Thanks!!

Comment: Might be a better question for gamedev.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your CCCallFuncO is calling `[self shoot:enemy2]` where `self` is the HelloWorldLayer object, but `shoot` is defined in the Enemies class.

**Edit:**

buffDude should be released before assigning it and retain it afterwards, like this:

Change this:

```
buffDude = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bigAndStrongEnemy.gif"];
```

to this:

```
[buffDude release];
buffDude = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bigAndStrongEnemy.gif"];
[buffDude retain];
```

This assumes that this is the only place where `buffDude` is assigned.  If it is also assigned elsewhere, make sure you properly retain and release it there as well.

Although, the more I think about it, I don't understand why you create a new `buffDude` every time `shoot` is called.  I'm not sure what you're doing, so I won't say it's wrong, but it doesn't look right to me anyway.

Comment: @Ed Marty yeah, that was when I was trying everything to get it to work, and I forgot to switch it back. Before, it was a redeclaration of buffDude, and then instead of self, it was buffDude.

Comment: I wonder, where does buffDude get stored?  It looks like you reassign buffDude whenever -shoot is called, but don't do anything with it, which will cause it to be autoreleased as soon as the autorelease pool is drained.  Then the next time you come around and try to call a method on it, it won't work because you're calling a method on an autoreleased object.

Comment: @Ed Marty I have an Enemies class as a subclass of CCSprite. I currently have buffDude declared in HelloWorldLayer like this: BigAndStrongEnemy *buffDude

Comment: The problem still exists then.  The problem is that you are creating an object, then trying to call a method on it after it's been released.

Comment: @Ed Marty so should I say to retain it?

Comment: My suggestion would be to release buffDude before reassigning it and then retain it after assigning it.

Comment: What's the error that it throws when it crashes?  Is it trying to call a method on an object that doesn't exist?  If so, try setting NSZombieEnabled (google it or look elsewhere on SO) to see if you can find out what object it's trying to use and step through the code yourself to see if you can find out where it's being released too early.

Comment: @Ed Marty It doesn't throw an error. I am using Xcode 4, does that make a difference? When it crashes, it goes to a line of code that is in the CCCallFunc file. It says 'Program recieved 'SIGABRT''

Comment: @Ed Marty what will NSZombieEnabled do?

Comment: See what I said above about it.

Answer (score 0):

from what i see (and the fact that i only worked with cocos2d-x) i can only tell you to test whether it steps inside your shoot funciton or not, but i guess you are somhow using `CCCallFuncO` bad, maybe you have to call it passing `enemy2` also for the `actionWithTarget` parameter (i can tell that becouse that's how cocos2d-x works), also check if big and small enemy types can be converted together freely.

Comment: what is cocos2d-x? I only know of Cocos2d